# Find the rows member of matrix in another matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two matrices as follow. I want to check the any member of rows in A which is in the B. For example, If I chose the second row in A(2) [7 12 a], since 12 is in the B(3), it gives me [12 13 b] or index 3. Or if I chose row 1 of A, since A(1)=[ 5 3 a], and 5 in the second row of B. The code gives me 2 or [5 10 b].

```
a= 100;
b= 200;

A= [5 3 a;
    7 12 a;
    9 10 a];
B =[1 6 b;
    5 10 b;
    12 13 b;
10 13 b];
```

I have used the ismember function, but I can not find the results. In summary:
`row_chosen_from_A = 3`
I want the index of B which includes any number of row_chosen_from_A.
 `results = 2, 4`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `'[LIA,LOCB] = ismember(A,B)'`.

`LOCB` shows the row number of `B` for each match. In your example the result for `LOCB` is:

```
LOCB =

 2     0     0
 0     3     0
 0     4     0
```

It means 5 in `A` is found in the second row of `B`, 12 in the third and 10 in the fourth.